# Read a SharePoint List and put the data on a HTML file through JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I have a SharePoint URL which is just a SharePoint list with some columns and rows of data.

I will like to read that information from that specific URL and put the data on a HTML file through a JavaScript function.

I have no experience about JavaScript & HTML5 at all so, I am not sure how to call to those functions in order to retrieve the data.

That's what I have so far and it is not working at all:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery.SPServices-0.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        webURL: "http://myURL.aspx",
        async: false,
        listName: "Announcements",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
          $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
            var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
            $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
          });
        }
      });
    });
</script>
<ul id="tasksUL"/>  
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

If I try to open the index.html nothing happens so I don't know how to call to my functions on my HTML file. Also, I don't know how to define SP.ClientContext in the HTML file.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: where do you define collList? Where did you get this snippet from?

Comment: I get it from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185009.aspx

Comment: ok, see my answer. Also, what do you mean by "nothing happens"? Do you get a blank page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SPServices library](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) will do that for you very easily.

You'll want to use [this](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems&referringTitle=Lists) call. I usually encapsulate it in my own function to make the code prettier, especially if I'm making a lot of AJAX list queries.

Basically what will happen is SharePoint will return an ugly XML document that has all your list items as defined by the [Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28v=office.14%29.aspx). You'll traverse this document using SPServices like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery.SPServices-0.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Announcements",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
        $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
<ul id="tasksUL"/>`
```

Line by line:
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>`
JQuery is required by SPServices
     `<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery.SPServices-0.6.2.min.js"></script>`
Including SPServices
     `$(document).ready(function() {`
"When the DOM is loaded, execute this function"
      `$().SPServices({`
"This is an SPServices function"
        `operation: "GetListItems",`
"We are using the 'GetListItems' web service"
        `async: false,`
"Not asynchronous, do it now"
        `listName: "Announcements",`
"We're using the list 'Announcements"
        `CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",`
Don't worry about this line
        `completefunc: function (xData, Status) {`
"Run this function when the request is complete. The data is passed as xData, the completion status is passed as Status"
          `$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {`
"Take the response string and only take the "row" XML nodes. For each of these nodes, run this function..."
            `var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";`
"Create a variable called liHtml equal to an li tag and the XML attribute ows_Title"
            `$("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);`
"Append this list item to the element with an ID of 'tasksUL'"

Comment: So... how can I embed that code on a html file? I am not clear about that. How is the function pointing to the SharePoint URL?

Comment: After taking a look to the documentation I had to add another "argument" to that call which is pretty much: webURL: "MyURL.aspx".

After that, once I open my index.html, nothing happens so looks like I am missing something here. I modified my first entry to change the index.html file

Comment: I am so sorry about that but I don't own that SharePoint list so I cannot provide the URL without permissions. I understand that you help might be limited about that but unfortunately it is not under my hands.

Even though, thanks a lot for all

Comment: Ah, then it's probably an authentication issue. You may need to do something like [this](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Authentication&referringTitle=%24%28%29.SPServices) before connecting. Just make sure that webURL is pointing to the domain of the SharePoint server otherwise the client won't have a context.

Comment: I tried to put the credentials:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $().SPServices({
   operation: "Login",
   webURL: "myURL.aspx",
   username: "domain\\username"
   password: "myPassword"
   operation: "GetListItems",

unfortunatelly still doesn't work

Comment: Does it means that I need to create two JavaScript functions? One for the Login and a new one for GetListItems?

Comment: Now I am debugging and getting the following error: breaking on jscript runtime error object doesn't support this property or method SPFilterNode

At least looks like it is executing the script

Comment: Looks like it is failing on that line: completefunc: function (xData, Status)
When I use the IE debug, that variable contains an error

Comment: That's what I am getting: '$' was used before it was defined.
  $(document).ready(function() { 

That one appears before than $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() which is the place where I am getting the error according to IE9 debugger.

Comment: I'm not too certain about this, but it could be that xData has no responseXML property because the request failed. Console.log xData and Status before you use them in the callback to see if you need error-checking.

Comment: After more investigation looks like the Requested URL status is: Status Code:401 Unauthorized

Comment: how did u add credentials here

Comment: @user388969 I answered that question in comment 4 on this thread.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of issues with your code.

First, it will only work in a SharePoint page, not as standalone, as you are using SharePoint functions like SP.ClientContext.

Second, there seems to be errors in the snippet. For example, I think `this.collList` should actually be `var collList`.

Maybe try this other reference (but again it'll only work within a SharePoint 2010 or 2013 page):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code you are using is for the SPServices library written by Sympmarc and there in its documentation its mention that it is to be used within the pages running on SharePoint Context as for making calls it uses __REQUESTDIGEST post variable and this will not be available on normal HTML5 pages, the options i can give to you are these:-

1) Enable Basic Http Authentication on the SharePoint Site and then use $ajax function of jquery with Basic Auth credentials in your call to service.

2)Create a http handler with code to do your work and then pass json from jquery to bring data from this handler.