# Consuming/reading data from sharepoint url

Tags: java, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint URL whose endpoint is .aspx page after browsing it into web page returns me list of names but when I am using it in my code it returns me entire HTML which is bit tricky to parse that information.
Can anyone suggest good approach to solve this

Edit:

I found below code on google

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.Credentials;
import org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.client.params.AuthPolicy;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.SPNegoSchemeFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeVersion;

public class SharPointClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{

        //Load Property
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));

        //Get exchange service object       
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);

        String passWd = prop.getProperty("mailPwd");
        String sharePointUser = prop.getProperty("sharePointUser");

        String BaseUrl = "http://server/default.aspx";

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpClient.getAuthSchemes().register(AuthPolicy.SPNEGO, new SPNegoSchemeFactory());

        /*Credentials useJaasCredentials = new Credentials() {
            public String getPassword() { return null; }
            public String getUserPrincipal() { return null; }
        };

        httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(null, -1, null),
            useJaasCredentials
        );*/

        httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,new NTCredentials(sharePointUser, passWd, "","mydomain"));

        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(BaseUrl);
        request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String results = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        System.out.println(results);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

this returns me response as entire HTML of that response which very tricky to parse so I tried to go through `JSoupe` but  that also seems to useless for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the sharepoint [REST Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx) interface. I guess what you need is List interface implementation. Can you check if the page returns a list. Else you have to scrape the html page which is a pain.

http://server_name/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx shows up methods for working with lists and list data.

Check examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478449/read-a-sharepoint-list-and-put-the-data-on-a-html-file-through-javascript-functi).

Comment: You are using  HttpUriRequest request to complete page. First check if the page you are accessing returns a list or not? Data displayed as LIST in web page is different.

Comment: It returns me response as web page with its HTML tags

Comment: I would not suggest scraping a web page, best is to see how is stored in sharepoint ( must be a list) so use list api as I suggested. If thats not possible, search for html tag ( DOM Path) where this list is. Use firebug or view source of page to find that. Write code to parse the DOM of web page and get the list. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it make sense but I don't want to use that approach. I thought for that way using JSoupe but after that I felt it's witty approach.